# Emulator show's spinner value's tablet show's empty value

Tags: java, android

In my application i use an MYSQL databank. And i try to load the value's from the Database into the spinner. In the (eclipse) emulator this works perfectally  (all items get loaded into the spinners) .

But when i try to run my application on my tablet (honeycomb 10.1) the value's from the database don't show up in the spinner. When i try to reach my database from the tablet everything works fine.

I'm also using the AsynTask for getting the data so that should not be the problem i think?

(The Code Below is working fine on the Emulator but when i load it on my honeycomb tab the data does not get loaded) And im using the AsynTask class to get the connectie to mysql

Any advice?

```
        // This Thread get's the reservation ID's
    Thread asyn = new Thread(){
       public void run(){
           try{
               int klok = 0;
               while(klok < 5000){
                   sleep(100);
                   klok = klok + 100;
               }

                try{
                            // Ophalen van de Reservaties objecten
                            lijst = mpr.get();


                            ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterCountries = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Materiaal.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            AdapterCountries.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


                            int lenLijst = lijst.size();

                            String[] temp = new String[lenLijst+1];

                            for(int x=0; x < lenLijst; x++){
                                temp[x] = Integer.toString(lijst.get(x).getRes_id());
                                AdapterCountries.add(temp[x]);

                                }



                            s1.setAdapter(AdapterCountries);



                    }catch(Exception ex){
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

           }catch(InterruptedException ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
    };

    asyn.start();
```

Comment: show us your code..!! for adding data to Adapter of `Spinner`

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed The Ip adress of your Database Server in your code?

Comment: I have added my code. There i nothing wrong with the IP address. The connection should also be fine i think it has something todo with te spinner?